# TeamCity - Compliation errros (third party reference assemblies and namespaces)

Tags: compilation, teamcity

I have TeamCity installed on build server and TFS on another server. Both are configured and set up so that when code is checked in via TFS, Teamcity detects those changes and builds the solution. I am able to successfully get to this stage of the set up. But I am getting lot of compile errors in TeamCity when I run a build configuration... All errors are like "so and so assembly reference is missing ... or name space could not be found... How can I include the references for those missing assemblies or namespaces in the Build server.. I am able to manually build successfully in my local development machine (which has all the third party references)... but it fails in the team city build server .. any one has a work around for this.. please let me know.. thank you

```
The type or namespace name 'Rhino' could not 
be found (are you missing a using directive    
an assembly reference?) 
The type or namespace name 'Ioperation' could not be found (are you missing a
using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two options.

1. Install the 3rd party assemblies on the Agent machine. You should avoid this if possible as it makes Agent maintance/adding new Agents a nightmare.
2. Store your 3rd party assemblies in your source control repository which are then checked out with your code on the Agent when a build is run. In Subversion you can do this with externals; I've never used TFS before but I assume there is a simular feature. The answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666597/tfs-vs2008-how-to-deal-with-external-assemblies) seems reasonable.

Everything you need to make your build work (e.g source code, 3rd part assemblies, resources etc) should be stored in your repository. This makes updating 3rd party assembly versions and scaling your Agent farm much easier

HTH